# Prove P$(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k|<\infty)>0 \iff$ P$(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k$ exists in $\mathbb R)=1$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, almost-everywhere

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of independent random variables, with $\mathbb E(X_n)=0$ and $|X_n|<K, \forall n,\omega$, then:

**P**$(\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}|\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_k|<\infty)>0 \iff$ **P**$(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}X_k$ exists in $\mathbb R)=1$

This can be also found in David Williams, probability with martingales (Remark in p.113). But this is not proven there.

---

New question deleted. It can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092968/random-signs-a-remark-of-david-williamsprobability-with-martingales).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"$\Leftarrow$" is obvious. For "$\Rightarrow$" we set $\sigma_k^2 = \mathbb{E}(X_k^2)$, $$M_n := \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \qquad \quad A_n := \sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2.$$ Using the independence of the random variables, it is not difficult to see that $(M_n^2-A_n)_{n \geq 0}$ is a martingale (with respect to the canonical filtration). For $r>0$ we define a stopping time $\tau$ by

$$\tau := \inf\{n; |M_n| > r\}.$$

Since, by assumption,

$$\mathbb{P} \left( \sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left| \sum_{k=1}^n X_k \right|<\infty \right)>0$$

we have $$\mathbb{P}(\tau=\infty)>0 \tag{1}$$ for $r$ sufficiently large.

By the optional stopping theorem,

$$\mathbb{E}(M_{n \wedge \tau}^2-A_{n \wedge \tau})=0;$$

hence,

$$\mathbb{E}A_{n \wedge \tau} = \mathbb{E}(M_{n \wedge \tau}^2) \leq (K+r)^2. \tag{2}$$

By $(1)$, we have $\tau(\omega)= \infty$ for each $\omega \in A$ for $r$ sufficiently large and some set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$. Therefore, $(2)$ implies by the monotone convergence theorem

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_k^2 < \infty.$$

This means that

$$\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} X_j \right)^2 \right] = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(X_j^2) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \sigma_j^2 <\infty.$$

In particular, $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} X_j<\infty$ almost surely.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! I will go trough it now and I hope I will understand it :)

Comment: @Epsilondelta You are welcome.

Comment: Okay, two questions (just to make sure that I understand it): 1) we have $\tau(\omega)=\infty$ because $|M_n|$ is bounded a.s. and if $r$ is bigger then the sup of $|M_n|$, then there is no $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $|M_n|>r$, hence $\tau(\omega)=\infty$, correct?. 2) Because of $\tau(\omega)=\infty$ for large $r$ and (2) holds for arbitrary $r$, we have $\mathbb E(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\sigma_k^2)\leq (K+r)^2<\infty$. We had a theorem in measure theory, that every integrable function is almost surely bounded. Thats exactly what you did here, correct? Thanks in advance, that helped me a lot! :)

Comment: @Epsilondelta 1. Yes. 2. Basically you are right. $(1)$ implies that for $r$ sufficiently large, we have $\mathbb{P}(\tau=\infty)>0$. By $(2)$ and the monotone convergence theorem, we have $$\mathbb{E}(1_{\{\tau=\infty\}} A_{\infty}) \leq (K+r)^2,$$ in particular, $A_{\infty}(\omega)<\infty$ for almost all $\omega \in \{\tau=\infty\}$. Since $\mathbb{P}(\tau=\infty)>0$, we can pick $\omega$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \sigma_k^2 = A_{\infty}(\omega) < \infty.$$ 3. Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I expanded my question above a bit. I hope you or someone else can take a look.

Comment: @Epsilondelta Instead of adding a new problem to this question, please ask a new question. Otherwise my answer looks out of place and confusion will arise...