# Question about a theorem of david williams:probability with martingales

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I am reading David Williams: Probability with martingales and got a questions:

At first a theorem:

[image]

**Now I want to know why the following holds:**

[image]

**The full proof of b):**

[image]

I was reading this prove many times. But unfortunately I can't see how the statement follows by the proof of b). Of course I tried it by myself, but (a) just yields that $\sum Var(X_k)=\infty$ if $\sum X_k=\sum \mathbb E(X_k^2)=\infty$, but I don't know how to connect this with the partial sums of $X_k$

I really hope that someone can go through it.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1091794/

Comment: It is a very strange remark, since it seems that the statement of (a) is more relevant to the remark. Perhaps it was a typo and meant to say "the proof of (a) showed" instead of "the proof of (b) showed"? Note that the condition that the partial sums are bounded is defined by the _tail behavior_ of the sequence, so the Kolmogorov 0-1 law implies the probability is 0 or 1.  If the probability is positive, then it must be 1. I wonder if the proof of part (a) shows that if the partial sums are all bounded (with probability 1) then the sum converges?

Comment: Or, it is being indirect in saying that if the partial sums are bounded with some positive probability, then for some $c$ we have $Pr[T=\infty]>0$ and so from (**) we conclude the sum of $\sigma_k^2$ is finite, which _from part (a)_ implies $\sum_k X_k$ converges almost surely.

Comment: The funny thing about equation (**) is that, regardless of whether "up-carrot" means "min" or "max" (I never remember which), we can still conclude $Pr[T=\infty]>0$ means $A_{\infty}<\infty$.